# SQL Server Profiler issue

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, deadlock, sql-server-profiler

I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise and I want to use SQL Server profiler to capture deadlock event only. And when deadlock occurs and event captured, I will stop SQL Server profiler.

My question is, since I launched SQL Server profiler, and before deadlock occur (event captured), any impact (more about performance impact) to database?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL profiler is another client of the database so it will impose some load, but quite little.

You can see how much CPU etc is used by looking as [sys.sysprocesses](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179881.aspx) for the SPID used by profiler.

However, you can also trap deadlock information to the SQL Server error log by [using trace flags 1204 and 1222](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188396.aspx). And [this link too](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104.aspx) for an overview.

Comment: If using Profiler before deadlock happens, how much percent do you think there will be performance impact? Any existing number public?

Comment: If no numeric data is also fine, if there could be some documents which claim performance impact is low, it will be also ok. Any available ones?

Comment: @George2: I don't know of any hard numbers or papers on the impact of profiling.

Comment: Thank you gbn, so "SQL profiler is another client of the database so it will impose some load, but quite little." -- how do you have this conclusion, from your experiment or experience or? :-)

Comment: @George2: experience. of course, if you choose to write every XML query plan to file then you'll kill the server (seen it happen), but if you're only tracing deadlocks then it's be acceptable. I'm running a trace now on my prod server... :-)